# XML errors in certain xml-files when starting eclipse. Resaving fixes

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, startup

So I have this really weird issue with certain xml-files and it's really starting to annoy me. Eclipse is telling me some xml-files contain errors, but simply resaving the files (by adding extra space or something) fixes the error, whatever the error was. This happends every time I start eclipse.

It says on the folder that there's error inside the folders that contain the xml-files giving errors, but the error icon on the file itself just shows for a split second after I expand the folder list. So I have to remember every time what names the xml-files with the problems had.

The error that seems to pop up in most of these xml-files is "Premature end of file". But like I said, simply resaving the file after adding an extra space or something, removes the error from the file, until I start eclipse the next time.

But I've also had other errors that are just a problem when eclipse starts.

I've tried cleaning the project several times, but it doesn't help.

Do someone have an idea what could cause this odd behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing 
if you have installed go on to the project  click
u will get a drop it would have a clean option
click it and then run the application again
CLEANING the project with help u out every time 
thanx 
raghav,